# How mongodb sorts the documents when an object is used as an index?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, multikey

If every document has an array of objects, let say :

```
hobbies:[
    {
        "title": "Swimming",
        "frequency": 4
    },
    {
        "title": "Playing",
        "frequency": 3
    }
]
```

and I use hobbies as an Index, then how all the documents in my db will be stored in an sorted manner? Which field will it consider to sort all the documents in index?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index on `hobbies` field like this as a [compound-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/index.html) :

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "hobbies.title": 1, "hobbies.frequency": 1 } )
```

So as `hobbies` is an array then eventually if you get `hobbies.title,hobbies.frequency` it will also be an array, So as if MongoDB finds an array to be indexed then it would create [multikey-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents) on that particular field (Basically in above scenario your document will be unwinded into two docs on `title & frequency` one for first object in array & another for second object in array in ascending order).